# openpyxl for Python 3 gives StringIO error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

When I try to load a workbook in Python 3.3 using openpyxl, I get a "No module named 'StringIO'" error:

```
In [5]: load_workbook(FileName)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-6-c4f3bc35f522>", line 1, in <module>
load_workbook(FileName)

File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-1.6.2-py3.3.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 112, in load_workbook
f = repair_central_directory(filename, is_file_instance)

File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-1.6.2-py3.3.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 59, in repair_central_directory
from StringIO import StringIO

ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

I am aware that StringIO is not available in Python 3, but then again, I am using the py3.3 version of openpyxl (or so I think...?).  However, when I try to find the file that calls StringIO, it is not in the directory noted in the traceback.  Have I installed something incorrectly?  Or is something else going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been resolved in openpyxl 1.7